# Stopping criteria for stochastic gradient descent?

Tags: stochastic-gradient-descent

When using stochastic gradient descent, how do we pick a stopping criteria?

A benefit of stochastic gradient descent is that, since it is stochastic, it can avoid getting stuck in a suboptimal region.

So I don't understand how we can pick a stopping criteria, because surely then we would be limiting the algorithm's ability to "unstuck" itself?

For gradient descent, I would typically use the norm of the gradient as a stopping criteria (so we stop when that norm is small enough).

Would this make sense for SGD too?

Answer (score 3):

We don't stop SGD because it stops dropping, we usually do it as a means of **preventing overfitting**.

In this sense we **don't** want it to reach the minimum, because this would entail memorizing the training set, which in turn [reduces generalization](https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/365806/119015).

As such, for a stopping criteria, usually we monitor the **validation loss**. This means that at the end of each epoch, we make a pass through the validation set and measure the validation loss. If we see that this stops dropping for a few iterations, we stop the training. Note that the training loss could still be dropping.

[image]