# Why is my validation loss always larger than my epoch loss

Tags: python, conv-neural-network, tensorflow, keras

I am training a CNN and it seems no that matter what I do my validation loss is always much greater than my training loss. To my understanding, this should mean my model is always overfitting my data set.

INFORMATION:
My model is built in Keras running on tensorflow=1.14.
My model is a binary cross-entropy.
I Have a data set of about 2500 tagged photos.
My tensor board:[image]

Comment: I think you're right: this sounds like [tag:overfitting]. Does this answer your question? [What should I do when my neural network doesn't generalize well?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365778/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-generalize-well)

Comment: The problem then is that its overfitting from the first epoch. I have a relatively decent-sized data set so does that mean that there is a problem with my network architecture?

Comment: Could be. Two of the suggestions in the linked thread are to try a different architecture, or a different regularization level. Using a neural network is a lot like picking a lock: you've got to line up all the tumblers just right or else the lock won't open. Likewise, you can't expect to immediately get a good model on the first try, but try different alternatives to get the desired result.