# DNN Cannot Stop Overfitting

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, overfitting

I am training a DNN (CNN + RNN) for a voice conversion task. Although my train loss can be very low with good performance, I believe I am experiencing massive overfitting. To overcome this, I have already added quite a bit of batch norm and dropout inside the model as well as weight decay — however, the model still continues to overfit a lot. I present some of my loss curves below:

With a weight decay constant of 1e-7:
[image: With a weight decay constant of 1e-7]

With a weight decay constant of 1e-2:
[image: With a weight decay constant of 1e-2]
Note that I noticed that if the weight decay constant is > 1e-4, the model seems to experience underfitting.

I want to know what else can I do to improve this model's generalization. Is it just a matter of more data, or do I need to modify my DNN architecture in some way. I have been struggling with this overfitting problem for some days now, and any insight would be a help.

Comment: What makes you think that weight decay of `1e-2` is overfitting? It looks like the training and validation setts have similar MSE, so it appears that this choice of weight decay is having the desired effect.

Comment: This [thread](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365778/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-generalize-well) provides a number of suggestions for how to address overfitting in neural networks. But as I've remarked in my comment, you may not have an overfitting problem at all, just a misunderstanding about what "overfitting" is. Responding to my comments or editing the post to clarify may allow this question to be reopened.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your response. On the weight decay of `1e-2`, I actually believed that the model may be *under*fitting, as you can see the training loss is far larger than the experiment with a weight decay of `1e-7`.

Comment: Why are x-scales so different between dev_loss (=?) and loss?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you're seeing with the loss of `1e-7` is a textbook case of overfitting. It should be obvious why a larger weight decay value *increases* the model's training loss. The training and holdout loss having approximately the same value shows that you've found the "goldilocks zone" that balances bias and variance for the model -- this is what you're trying to achieve by using a [regularization](/questions/tagged/regularization) technique.