# Validation loss very high

Tags: neural-networks, validation

[image]

The validation loss is decreasing very slowly and the accuracy after 100 epochs is significantly lower than the train accuracy.
What seems to be the problem here and how can I fix it?
Do I decrease the number of nodes in the hidden layer, or use dropout?

Comment: [What should I do when my neural network doesn't generalize well?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/365778/what-should-i-do-when-my-neural-network-doesnt-generalize-well)

Comment: You can try reducing the complexity of your model, and use regularization.